# OnImageAvailableListener is not being invoked for Camera2 API for taking a photo

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, image-reader

I am trying to take a photo using the Camera2 API. The API is currently used to produce a preview on a SurfaceView on my screen which works fine, but when i try to capture image, the OnImageAvailable listener doesn't get called at all. I need this to produce an image file which can then be used on my next screens.

The code is based on this sample project https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Handler.Callback{
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    static final String TAG = "CamTest";
    static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1242;
    private static final int MSG_CAMERA_OPENED = 1;
    private static final int MSG_SURFACE_READY = 2;
    private File mFile;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private CameraManager mCameraManager;
    private String[] mCameraIDsList;
    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraStateCB;
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;
    private CaptureRequest mPreviewRequest;
    boolean mSurfaceCreated = true;
    boolean mIsCameraConfigured = false;
    private Surface mCameraSurface = null;
    private ImageReader mImageReader;
    private int width = 400;
    private int height = 500;
    private String mCameraId;
    private static final int STATE_PREVIEW = 0;
    private static final int STATE_WAITING_LOCK = 1;
    private static final int STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE = 2;
    private static final int STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE = 3;
    private static final int STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN = 4;
    private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH = 1920;
    private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 1080;
    private int mState = STATE_PREVIEW;
    private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);
    private boolean mFlashSupported;
    private int mSensorOrientation;
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;
    private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        mCameraSurface = surfaceHolder.getSurface();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        mCameraSurface = surfaceHolder.getSurface();
        mSurfaceCreated = true;
        mBackgroundHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_SURFACE_READY);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        mSurfaceCreated = false;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public CameraFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static CameraFragment newInstance() {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        CameraFragment fragment = new CameraFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static CameraFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        CameraFragment fragment = new CameraFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener onImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader){
            Log.i("Image Available", "Image Available");
            mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), mFile));
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        this.mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        this.mSurfaceHolder = this.mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        this.mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try {
            mCameraIDsList = this.mCameraManager.getCameraIdList();
            for (String id : mCameraIDsList) {
                Log.v(TAG, "CameraID: " + id);
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        mCameraStateCB = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
                mCameraDevice = camera;
                mBackgroundHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_CAMERA_OPENED);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            }
        };

        TabLayout tabLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if(tab.getText().equals(getString(R.string.gallery))){
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                            HomeFragment.newInstance()).commit();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        ImageButton imageButton = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.captureImgBtn);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            lockFocus();
            captureImage();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
                       throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "pic.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        startBackgroundThread();
        //requesting permission
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                mCameraManager.openCamera(mCameraIDsList[1], mCameraStateCB, new Handler());
                setUpCameraOutputs(width, height);

            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startBackgroundThread();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        try {
            if (mCaptureSession != null) {
                mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
                mCaptureSession.close();
                mCaptureSession = null;
            }

            mIsCameraConfigured = false;
        } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IllegalStateException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (mCameraDevice != null) {
                mCameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
                mCaptureSession = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void captureImage (){
        try {
            mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraDevice.getId());
            List<Surface> surfaces =new ArrayList<>(2);
            Size[] jpegSizes;
            jpegSizes = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                    CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
            mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,
                    mBackgroundHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    private void captureStillPicture() {
        try {
            final Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null == activity || null == mCameraDevice) {
                return;
            }
            // This is the CaptureRequest.Builder that we use to take a picture.
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder =
                    mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

            // Use the same AE and AF modes as the preview.
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            setAutoFlash(captureBuilder);

            // Orientation
            int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation(rotation));

            CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback
                    = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                               @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                               @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, mFile.toString());
                    unlockFocus();
                }
            };

            mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
            mCaptureSession.abortCaptures();
            mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Lock the focus as the first step for a still image capture.
     */
    private void lockFocus() {
        try {
            // This is how to tell the camera to lock focus.
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                    CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
            // Tell #mCaptureCallback to wait for the lock.
            mState = STATE_WAITING_LOCK;
            mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,
                    mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void unlockFocus() {
        try {
            // Reset the auto-focus trigger
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                    CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
            setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);
            mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,
                    mBackgroundHandler);
            // After this, the camera will go back to the normal state of preview.
            mState = STATE_PREVIEW;
            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, mCaptureCallback,
                    mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private int getOrientation(int rotation) {
        // Sensor orientation is 90 for most devices, or 270 for some devices (eg. Nexus 5X)
        // We have to take that into account and rotate JPEG properly.
        // For devices with orientation of 90, we simply return our mapping from ORIENTATIONS.
        // For devices with orientation of 270, we need to rotate the JPEG 180 degrees.
        return (ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation) + mSensorOrientation + 270) % 360;
    }


    private void setAutoFlash(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
        if (mFlashSupported) {
            requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_CAMERA_OPENED:
            case MSG_SURFACE_READY:
                // if both surface is created and camera device is opened
                // - ready to set up preview and other things
                if (mSurfaceCreated && (mCameraDevice != null)
                        && !mIsCameraConfigured) {
                    configureCamera();
                }
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(this);
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void configureCamera() {
        // prepare list of surfaces to be used in capture requests
        List<Surface> sfl = new ArrayList<Surface>();

        sfl.add(mCameraSurface); // surface for viewfinder preview

        // configure camera with all the surfaces to be ever used
        try {
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(sfl,
                    new CaptureSessionListener(), mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mIsCameraConfigured = true;
    }




    private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {


        private final Image mImage;

        private final File mFile;

        ImageSaver(Image image, File file) {
            mImage = image;
            mFile = file;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            FileOutputStream output = null;
            try {
                Log.i("File path", mFile.getAbsolutePath());
                output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                output.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mImage.close();
                if (null != output) {
                    try {
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                        = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

                // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
                Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
                if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                    continue;
                }

                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(
                        CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                if (map == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                // For still image captures, we use the largest available size.
                Size largest = Collections.max(
                        Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                        new CompareSizesByArea());
                mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
                        ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);
                mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);


                // Find out if we need to swap dimension to get the preview size relative to sensor
                // coordinate.
                int displayRotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
                boolean swappedDimensions = false;
                switch (displayRotation) {
                    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270) {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180) {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e(TAG, "Display rotation is invalid: " + displayRotation);
                }

                Point displaySize = new Point();
                activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
                int rotatedPreviewWidth = width;
                int rotatedPreviewHeight = height;
                int maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.x;
                int maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.y;

                if (swappedDimensions) {
                    rotatedPreviewWidth = height;
                    rotatedPreviewHeight = width;
                    maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.y;
                    maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.x;
                }

                if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {
                    maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;
                }

                if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT) {
                    maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
                }



                // Check if the flash is supported.
                Boolean available = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
                mFlashSupported = available == null ? false : available;

                mCameraId = cameraId;
                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }
    }

    /**
     * Compares two {@code Size}s based on their areas.
     */
    static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            // We cast here to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }

    }



    private class CaptureSessionListener extends
            CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback {



        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(final CameraCaptureSession session) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CaptureSessionConfigure failed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onReady(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
            super.onReady(session);

        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigured(final CameraCaptureSession session) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CaptureSessionConfigure onConfigured");
            mCaptureSession = session;

            try {
                mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice
                        .createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
                mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mCameraSurface);
                mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(),
                        null, null);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "setting up preview failed");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback
            = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        private void process(CaptureResult result) {
            switch (mState) {
                case STATE_PREVIEW: {
                    // We have nothing to do when the camera preview is working normally.
                    break;
                }
                case STATE_WAITING_LOCK: {
                    Integer afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
                    if (afState == null) {
                        captureStillPicture();
                    } else if (CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState ||
                            CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState) {
                        // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                        Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                        if (aeState == null ||
                                aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                            mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                            captureStillPicture();
                        } else {
                            //runPrecaptureSequence();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE: {
                    // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                    Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                    if (aeState == null ||
                            aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE ||
                            aeState == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED) {
                        mState = STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE: {
                    // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                    Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                    if (aeState == null || aeState != CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE) {
                        mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                        captureStillPicture();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
    };



        @Override
        public void onCaptureProgressed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                        @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                        @NonNull CaptureResult partialResult) {
            process(partialResult);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {

            Log.i("Capture Completed", "true");
            process(result);

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

createCaptureSession() needs a list of "target", but you only added mCameraSurface. You should add mImageReader.getSurface() too.